# What technological means are there to go faster than warp 10?

Tags: star-trek, propulsion

I'm wondering what technological means there are in Star Trek to go faster than warp 10.

To state the question more precisely: you can use a wormhole, a Q, a Traveller and so on to accomplish the same result (getting far away very fast). But those methods are somewhat "natural". Also I don't consider teleporting a mean to go faster than warp 10, because basically that's just disappearing at one place and instantaneously reappearing somewhere else.

What I'm actually looking for are technologies like Transwarp Coils, the [displacement wave](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Displacement_wave) used by the Caretaker to bring Voyager to the Delta Quadrant, [the Graviton Catapult](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Graviton_catapult)... so I'm looking for technological inventions that let you fly *real* fast.

Comment: There are literally dozens. Too many to list without it becoming a "list question".

Comment: @Richard Are there? I thought so too, but when I started thinking about it, I only came back with a handful.

Comment: If you're speaking of "going to Warp 10.1" then the answer is "none". If you mean "simply going faster as Warp 9.9 goes" then the answer is "a lot".

Comment: @Bobby I mean a number greater than 10, so 10.1 qualifies. And I am sure there are some technologies to do that - I already gave some examples...

Comment: @PaulDWaite my hyphenation is still work in progress ;-)

Comment: Problem is of course: What is warp 10 anyway? In the "old days", warp 10 was just $1000 c$, so could be exceeded with mayn technologies and phenomena. In STTNG, warp 10 is by definition *inifite* velocity, that is you arrive at any destination the very moment you start (cf. STVOY *Treshold*). Anything beyond tat would require you to arrive *before* you start, so one should just list all methods of (backward) tikme travel. - Alright, the warp scale was redesigned (again) for the future in *All Good Things* to allow warp 13 as a regular speed ..., so how fast is warp 10 really?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's a fair question. We know that on maximum speed it would take Voyager some 80 to get home. That's at warp 9.97 or so. What do they have to do to their engine to get there in say 40 years or 10 years or five minutes? Warp 13 and above would be the requirement I guess. Anyhow: A valid question!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - I assumed he meant the recalibrated warp 10

Comment: I agree with @Bobby, the answer is none. Who says that Q isn't just going insanely fast (like warp 9.9999999999, which would seem instant but not actually break the Warp 10 barrier). This would be the same for all the other techs too including the Iconian gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Warp_drive) site lists many of the sorts of transwarp technologies you're listed above (as well as a bunch more) that have been shown to help ships break the warp 10 barrier.

**Transwarp Drive

Quantum Slipstream Drive

Artificial Wormholes

The Displacement Wave

Trans-Dimentional Gateways

Graviton Catapults**

And semi-technical/magical methods such as;

**Being "snapped" there by a Q

Being 'augmented' by a Traveller

Being snapped there by a Dowd

Slingshot Effect**

[Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Transwarp) lists many more including;

**Hyperwarp drive

Transwarp conduits

Transwarp Gates

Transwarp Portal

Timewarp Transfactors**

etc 
etc

Comment: I'd filter out Q and Traveller since those are (as stated in OP more "natural" ways), also I'm uncertain if the slingshot is an technological invention. Otherwise I'd say this is the answer!

Comment: Except for the artificial wormholes (I forgot about them completely - thanks!) those five were those I came up with. It surprised/surprises me that there are so few ways...

Comment: By the Trans-Dimensional Gateway you mean the Iconian technology? If so: The way I recall it, you step through it and then you are somewhere else. It brings you faster from A to B as going by warp 10+ would do, but it cannot make your ship fly faster than warp 10. It's more a form of teleporting, ain't it?

Comment: @einer - That's the one. Tom Paris makes a passing reference to an Iconian gateway being able to transport the entire Voyager back to Earth. It's not clear if this is a real or merely theoretical technology. I see no reason one of their portals couldn't be ship-sized.

Comment: I don't see a reason why such a gate couldn't be scaled up. But still there is no real movement/speed involved: You disappear on one side and reappear on the other. It relocates you quickly, but your ship is actually barely moving: Maybe they would enter the gate at 1/4 impulse. The ship flies _slowly_ - and suddenly appears somewhere else.